# how to search unpaired bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, search, bluetooth, device

I'm doing an app which uses bluetooth communication.

At first, I'm trying to get a list of all bluetooth devices detectable by the device.

I've managed to load in a listview all the paired devices, but i'm unable to list un-paired devices, I've found some tutorials but I'm a bit confused as I'm a bit new to android development & bluetooth communication.

So i need to find every bluetooth device in range, and I don't know how to do it (lazy)

Here is the (edited) code:

package com.voice.benz.instaurentremote;

```
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.Set;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.view.Window;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class bluetooth extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView bluetoothPaired;
    private TextView txt_status;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

    private ListView newdevices_listview;

    private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
    private static final int BLUETOOTH_ON = 1000;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

        // Initialize the button to perform device discovery

        txt_status          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_status);


        newdevices_listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.newdevices_listview);
        adapter=new             ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        newdevices_listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Initialize adapter
        btAdapter =  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


// Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                //discovery starts, we can show progress dialog or perform other tasks
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                //discovery finishes, dismis progress dialog
            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                //bluetooth device found
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                txt_status.setText("Found device " + device.getName());
                adapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };



    public void attivaBluetooth (View view) {

        if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOn, 1);

        }
    }

        public void cercaDispositivi (View view)
    {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    public void disattivaBluetooth (View view)
    {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            btAdapter.disable();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bluetooth, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be registering your BroadcastReceiver `myBluetoothReceiver` anywhere. If you do that in `onResume()` or `onCreate` you'll probably have more luck. :)

Comment: I've edited the code, now it partially working.
When i press the button "look for devices" on my app, it does nothing, but when i associate a device with the one where the app its running, once the pairing its done, the app shows the paired devices in the listview.
By the way this is not what I need, because when I press "look for devices" button, nothing happens, looks like I'm missing something